# Отслеживание изменения статуса интернета

Tags: java, android, android-broadcastreceiver

Доброго времени суток. Необходимо в активити при отключении интернета выводить соответствующее сообщение. Пытаясь разобраться в этой теме, я еще больше запутался.
Насколько я понял, нужно создать приемник широковещательных сообщений (создать класс наследующий `BroadcastReceiver`), затем в активити зарегистрировать этот приемник широковещательных сообщений. А вот далее возникает два вопроса:

1. Допустим отправляется сообщение что пропал интернет, соответственно срабатывает метод `onReceive`, но ведь активити то ничего не знает об этом? Как соответственно передать в активити эту информацию?
2. Как все же реализовать отправку сообщений для приемника об изменении статуса интернета(в интернете нашел, что надо использовать `ConnectivityManager`)?

Comment: По 1 пункту сам разобрался, остается второй пункт.

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае проще всего будет зарегистрировать `BroadcastReceiver` в коде `Activity`. А для детектирования изменения статуса подключения, надо ловить `action "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"`.

В **MainActivity.java**

```
private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(
                "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");

        mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                if (!isNetworkAvailable())
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Соединение с Интернет было потеряно", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        };
        this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        this.unregisterReceiver(this.mReceiver);
    }

private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
          = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

В **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```